# Why do Intellij default getter/setter templates delete my boolean "is" variable name prefix?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style

I have an entity. I defined variable as boolean and I created Getter and Setter methods with Intellij Idea Shortcuts.

```
private Boolean isForLaboratory = false;
```

[image: ddasd]

[image]

After creation it generated this:

```
public Boolean getForLaboratory() {
    return isForLaboratory;
}

public void setForLaboratory(Boolean forLaboratory) {
    isForLaboratory = forLaboratory;
}
```

I expected getIsForLaboratory and setIsForLaboratory. Is it general convention for Java? Why Intellij deleted my prefixes?

Comment: Boolean is a wrapper class, use lowercase primitive boolean.. and yes, omitting is in the getter/setters is convention. Consider isPlaying. We would set to Playing and get Playing or not.

Comment: This is a convention.  IntelliJ is assuming that the base name is `ForLaboratory` and that the `is` part is only present because you are using a boolean.  Try it with `String isForLaboratory` and you will see this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pop up the Dialog to `Generate` the `Getter and Setter`, you can see:

```
Getter template: IntelliJ Default
Setter template: IntelliJ Default
```

Click on the button to the right of `Getter Template` labelled with `...` and you can see the template code includes the following:

```
#if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($name, 'is'))
  #set($name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name))
#else
  is##
```

In other words there is special handling for fields starting with `is` - and if you want to write your own template, you can of course do this :)

As for why - there is a javabeans standard for boolean fields where the getter for a field named (for example) `boolean enabled` can be `isEnabled()` instead of `getEnabled()`, and it's surely related to this.

Comment: suggestion: maybe rename your property to `forLaboratory`. Therefore the getter would be `isForLaboratory()` - per default template.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ version 15+, you have to use primitive boolean to make IntelliJ generate a Get function with "is" prefix.

the default `Getter Template` looks like this:

```
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  #if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($name, 'is'))
    #set($name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name))
  #else
    is##
#end
```

So the correct way in IntelliJ 15.x and up should be like this:

```
private boolean forLaboratory = false;
```

after auto generation:

```
public boolean getForLaboratory() {
    return forLaboratory;
}

public void isForLaboratory(boolean forLaboratory) {
    this.forLaboratory = forLaboratory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue recently while I was working on a Spring boot application with spring data MongoDB. For isDeleted property there was two key in the database. `isDeleted` and `deleted`.

While i was investigating i found that in my Document java class the `isDeleted` property was getting exposed with `getDeleted` and `setDeleted` method instead of `getIsDeleted` and `setIsDeleted`. Here is a sneak peak of the document class:
**Before**

```
public class Book {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;

    public Boolean getDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
        isDeleted = deleted;
    }

   // other getters and setters omitted
}
```

This was happening because I was utilizing `Intellij Idea`'s getters and setters generation feature.

I figured this can be changed easily by modifying the existing code generation template available in `Intellij Idea`.

To Add new Custom Getters And Setters Template follow this:

```
Open Any Java File > Press ALT + INS > Getters and Setters > Select ... Symbol > Press + Sign on the pop up box > Enter template name > Paste New Template > Press Save
```

Afterwards, while generating the getters and setters just select your custom template and press ok. **And it should fix your problem.**

**After**

```
    public class Book {
        private Long id;
        private String title;
        private Boolean isDeleted = false;
    
        public Boolean getIsDeleted() {
          return isDeleted;
        }
    
        public void setIsDeleted(Boolean isDeleted) {
          this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
        }
    
        // other getters and setters omitted
        }
```

Here is my custom templates which fix this issue:

1. Modified Intellij Default `Getters` Generation Template

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#if($field.recordComponent)
  ${field.name}##
#else
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.name.startsWith("is"))
  getIs##
#else
  get##
#end
${name}##
#end
() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

2. Modified Intellij Default `Setters` Generation Template

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
void ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.name.startsWith("is"))
  #set ($paramName = $field.name)
  setIs##
#else
  set##
#end
${name}($field.type $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
    $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

3. Modified Builder Pattern `Setters` Generation Template

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static void ##
#else
  $classSignature ##
#end
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.name.startsWith("is"))
    #set ($paramName = $field.name)
setIs##
#else
set##
#end
${name}($field.type $paramName) {
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
  #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
  this.##
  #else
    $classname.##
  #end
#end
$field.name = $paramName;
#if(!$field.modifierStatic)
return this;
#end
}
```