# Customize default getter/setter template in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation, getter-setter

I have created a **custom template** for setters in *IntelliJ*.
I can chose that template when I use <kbd>Alt + Insert</kbd> and it works great.

However when I try to press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> to generate a missing setter it uses the IntelliJ default.

How to make the Alt+Enter completion use my custom template instead of the default?

Comment: Can't reproduce in 2016.3.4 version. Whatever template was last used in Alt+Insert dialog will be used in the Alt+Enter intention as well.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Did you add a setting for that? I just tried it myself and whenever I use Alt+Enter it uses the standard setter even though the custom template is the standard when I use Alt+Insert

Comment: There are no additional settings. I just added a template and selected it on Alt+Insert, then the same template was used on Alt+Enter.

Answer (score 2):

Using <kbd>Alt + Insert</kbd> to [Generate getters and setters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html#generate-getters-setters), a dialog opens, where you can customize the *default template* used by IntelliJ by clicking on the **3 dots** button `...`.

[image: dialog (dark mode)]

or

[image: dialog steps]

Next the respective dialog will open, for example [Generate Setter Dialogue](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-setter-dialog.html). You can duplicate the default template (named 'IntelliJ Default') and adapt the copy to your needs. For a detailed description of template-variables see [Getter/Setter Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html#customize-templates).

The customized template will also be used when pressing <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> to open *intention actions* in the context-menu.

#### See also

- tutorial on Medium (2020): [Custom Getter/Setter Templates for Intellij IDEA](https://omindu.medium.com/custom-getter-setter-templates-for-intellij-idea-52177277ff0a)
- [Why do Intellij default getter/setter templates delete my boolean "is" variable name prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801457/why-do-intellij-default-getter-setter-templates-delete-my-boolean-is-variable)
- [Is there a way to generate JavaFX getters/setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579506/is-there-a-way-to-generate-javafx-getters-setters)