# Is there a way to generate JavaFX getters/setters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

```
MyBean {
    private final IntegerProperty number = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public IntegerProperty numberProperty(){
        return number;
    }
    public final int getNumber(){
        return numberProperty().get();
    } 
    public final void setNumber(int number){
        numberProperty().set(number);
}
```

e(fx)clipse Plugin gives Eclipse a generate command, which will generate JavaFX getters/ setters like above.
Is there something similar for IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Alt+Insert, Generate getters and setters?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can write your own getter setter style and use it.

1. Alt + Insert
2. Getter-Setter
3. Click getter template -> Click new Template and write your own template script. Save
   [image]4. Do same for the setter.