# Wrap class attributes with properties javafx

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

Suppose we have the following class:

```java
public class Person(){
    String name;
    String lastName;
    public String getName(){return name}
    public String getLastName(){return lastName}
    public void setLastName(String lastName){this.lastName = lastName}
    public void setName(String name){this.name = name}
```

Then we develop a JavaFX app and want to use data binding, therefore we should have a class like the following:

```java
public class Person(){
    StringProperty name;
    StringProperty lastName;
    public StringProperty NameProperty(){return name}
    public StringProperty LastNameProperty(){return lastName}
    public String getName(){return name.get()}
    public String getLastName(){return lastName.get()}
    public void setLastName(String lastName){this.lastName.set(lastName)}
    public void setName(String name){this.name.set(name)}
```

This requires rewriting all the class from scratch, is there a way of wrapping the attributes of the first class to avoid creating a whole new class?

Comment: Not really, no. Note that you can just replace the first class with the second, because the functionality of the first is a subset of the functionality of the second (though you may want a version that's used in an environment without the JavaFX libraries).

Comment: You could try and make use of the `javafx.beans.property.adapter` package, though it would probably be easier to combine that with a `PersonAdapter` class that wraps a `Person`. But all of this still involves writing a lot of boilerplate. And keep in mind that if your original `Person` class is not observable (via `java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`) then the JavaFX adapters won't be able to automatically update or fire change events if the underlying `Person` object is modified directly.

Comment: It seems that it is easier to just write the class from scratch; anyway, thanks.

Comment: I think in Netbeans, you can create the properties and Netbeans can generate all the methods and constructors for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579506/is-there-a-way-to-generate-javafx-getters-setters

Comment: I have not tried this https://github.com/Tuupertunut/JavaFXGetterGenerator.

Comment: [e(fx)clipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/efxclipse) has similar functionality

Comment: Intellij Idea does a good job of generating all of the JavaFX Bean methods.

Comment: This kind of situation does come up from time to time - where the domain object maps perfectly to the GUI model.  However, depending on the architecture that you're using (MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc), your GUI model is going to have only particular fields from your domain objects, and it's likely to be a composite of several domain objects and have other control type properties and properties that represent business/application logic that are needed by the GUI.  So using an adapter or some other wrapper is usually not a great approach.